# How to redirect non www or non http to https://www.example.com

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting

I have written below rule in web.config

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It works well for the below url

www.example.com 
http://example.com , 
http://www.example.com, 
https://www.example.com and 
example.com

but not works for **`https://example.com`** . I wanted to rewrite it to **`https://www.example.com`**

what will be the required changes so it will be achieve?

Comment: which type of certificate you are using self-signed, domain etc?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my rewrite rule to this and my problem is resolved.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^80$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```